# Should namespaces in Unity3d start with Assets.?

Tags: unity-game-engine, namespaces, resharper

Every time I let ReSharper rearrange my namespaces, let's say we have a script in `Scripts/MyMonoBehaviour.cs`  ReSharper says that the corresponding namespace to this file is  `Assets.Scripts` while I consider it to be simply Scripts(judging by [GPG Plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) for Unity3d which scripts' namespaces start with `GooglePlayGames.` and not with `Assets.GooglePlayGames`).

How can I tell ReSharper to exclude the Assets from the potential namespace refactoring?

Comment: I think your script folder is in assets folder thats why resharper suggesting the same.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan first thank you very much for the quick response!
Yes, my Scripts folder is in the Assets folder as is GooglePlayGames folder. In Unity3d at least as far as I'm concerned all folders that we create for scripts and not only are at ...ProjectName/Assets... directory and still I find many projects omitting the Assets. in their namespaces and not sure why they do it.

Comment: Have a look on https://confluence.jetbrains.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/37234581 to ommit the assets in namespaces

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan thanks! The namespace provider option seems to do the job quite easily! :))) I think it's a good fit for an answer for my question.

Comment: posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your script folder is in assets folder that's why `Resharper` suggesting the same.

In order to omit any particular folder from a namespace have a look on [**here**](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/37234581).

Comment: link is broken. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you install the [Unity extension for ReSharper](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity#readme), it will automatically disable `Assets` and `Assets.Scripts` from being suggested as part of the namespace.